# PyQT/PySide - Button and lineEdit not working on Second Window

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, pyqt6

I successfully created a second window (ChiffrerWindow) but whenever I try to click a button in the second window nothing happens (The button don't execute the slots). They behave like blank widgets

I have 5 files ui_mainwindow.py and ui_chiffrerwindow.py (Which are generated from QtDesigner), chiffrerwindow.py and mainwindow.py (Are the corresponding files where I pass in the slots),
main.py (Executes the app).
This is my mainwindow.py (I didn't show the top file imports)

```
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_chiffrerwindow import Ui_ChiffrerWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow,Ui_ChiffrerWindow):
    def __init__(self,app):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.actionChiffrer.triggered.connect(self.ouvrirChiffrer)
        
    def ouvrirChiffrer(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_ChiffrerWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
```

This is my chiffrerwindow.py

```
from ui_chiffrerwindow import Ui_ChiffrerWindow
class ChiffrerWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_ChiffrerWindow):
    def __init__(self,app):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ui = Ui_ChiffrerWindow()

        # self.getFileToEncrypt = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButtonFileDirCrypt")
        # self.getPubKeyToEncrypt = self.findChild(QPushButton, "pushButtonPubKeyCrypt")
        # self.line_edit_file_dir = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEditFileDirCrypt")
        # self.ine_edit_pub_key = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "lineEditPubKeyCrypt")
        
        self.ui.pushButtonFileDirCrypt.clicked.connect(self.getFileToEncrypt)
        self.ui.pushButtonPubKeyCrypt.clicked.connect(self.getPubKeyToEncrypt)
    
    def getFileToEncrypt(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open File","", "All Files (*);; Word Documents (*.docx)")

        # Output file name
        if fname:
            self.ui.lineEditFileDirCrypt.setText(fname[0])

    
    def getPubKeyToEncrypt(self):
        print("You want to get the keys to encrypt the file")
```

This is what my app looks like. This is the main window
[This is the main window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oKWw.png)

This is the second window
[This is the second window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piMHf.png). Whenever I click the buttons on the second window I would like to open a File Dialog to permit to the user to select a file.

I am a beginner and this is a project of implementing PGP cryptography in a desktop app.
Thank you very much for your concern and your help

Comment: The windows are made with two different classes, the event won't be able to connect to the function, try defining the variables outside of the class so they can be accessed by all classes.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. But I imported these classes. Importing doesn't solve the connecting problem (Just asking I'll still try what you said)

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. Is there any other way possible thing I could try. Or maybe I did what you said wrong

Comment: You're never using the `ChiffrerWindow` since you're never importing the `chiffrerwindow.py` file. Also: `MainWindow` should only inherit from `QMainWindow` and `Ui_MainWindow`, certainly **not** `Ui_ChiffrerWindow`. In the main script just do `from chiffrerwindow import ChiffrerWindow` and only do `self.window = ChiffrerWindow()` and `self.window.show()`.